# Jquery toggles open and close automatically in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have implemented some code which works on desktop, but in mobile, it does not work as expected.
In mobile, when you click on a div, it should toggle to open up the contents. However, it opens it, then closes it again automatically so the user doesn't get to see the contents.
Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.contact_Style h2.general_Click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
});

<h2 class="general_Click">Search </h2>
<div id="search">The Content</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind to `click`, because of mobile browsers trigger it on touch, so you get 2 callback calls (Which open and then close content).

You can read about this behavior [here](http://ariatemplates.com/blog/2014/05/ghost-clicks-in-mobile-browsers/)

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, I don't know how to apply it to my particular scenario.

Comment: Instead of binding to `click touchstart` events, use only `click`, so you'll get this: `$(document).on('click', '.contact_Style h2.general_Click', ...`

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small correction in your code. 
At first you need to hide your content div by default.
Add this in your style file:

```
#search{display: none}
```

Then try to use this js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'h2.general_Click', function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    }); 
</script>
```

Your html would be as it is:

```
<h2 class="general_Click">Search </h2>

<div id="search">The Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case selector "h2.general_Click" is created 2 times (Please check in your view-source) and that is why it is calling 2 times and closed automatically

Please check your view-source code that your selector is not repeating.
If it is repeating then select a sector that do not repeat in your web page.